# What's the difference between webpack:/// and webpack:?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, source-maps

I am trying to setup launch.json in VS Code to debug Angular application. I find from online research that we need to set sourceMapPathOverrides to set source mapping path. I have seen some different mappings. I am just wondering if there is any difference between the following two:

```
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/*"
       }
```

```
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///./*": "${webRoot}/*"
       }
```

I've tried both myself and I don't find any difference.

Answer (score -1):

In the context of setting up the sourceMapPathOverrides for debugging an Angular application in VS Code, the two configurations you've provided are functionally equivalent. Both configurations achieve the same goal of mapping the paths of source-mapped files from the webpack bundle to the corresponding files in your web application's source code directory.

The sourceMapPathOverrides configuration is used to adjust the paths of source files that are mentioned in the source maps generated by webpack. This adjustment is necessary because the paths in the source maps often don't directly match the paths in your local development environment.

The reason you're not finding any difference between the two configurations you've tried is that both configurations use wildcards to match and replace paths. In your case, "webpack:/*" and "webpack:///./*" are both matching any path within the webpack bundle and replacing it with ${webRoot}/*. The ${webRoot} variable represents the root directory of your web application in the debugger.

Both configurations will achieve the desired outcome: allowing the debugger to correctly map the paths of source files from the webpack bundle to the corresponding files in your Angular application's source code. You can use either of these configurations without any significant difference in behavior.

In summary, you can choose either of the configurations you've mentioned based on your preference. Since they both serve the same purpose and provide the same result, it's more about which configuration you find more readable or intuitive.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Why do we have to use three slashes in the second option? If I were to use two slashes as in '//./' , it would not work.